# Cannot change value of textbox from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I am trying to do here is to remove any text from the textbox if the check box is unchecked. I am trying to do that using `document.getElementsById(textBoxID).value = ''`, but it has no effect. What mistake am I doing. The corresponding code is shown below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="YourEMail" id="YourEMail" style="width: 250px;"> 
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="enableDisable(this.checked, 'YourEMail')" name="check_sendToEmail" value="sendToEmail">
  <span style="color:cyan;">Send output to e-mail</span><br>
  <script>
  document.getElementById('YourEMail').disabled = true</script>
  </script>

  <script>
  function enableDisable(bEnable, textBoxID)
  {
   document.getElementById(textBoxID).disabled = !bEnable
   if (document.getElementById(textBoxID).disabled)
    document.getElementsById(textBoxID).value = ''
  }
  </script>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Value`? Should be `value`, it's case sensitive...

Comment: Still doesn't work!

Comment: You should've started with looking at your console: `TypeError: document.getElementsById is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo @ **`getElementsById`** and **`Value`**

What made you put `s` in last statement ? Also note that properties are case sensitive hence `value` and `Value` are different. There is no **`Value`** property of `InputElement`

```js
document.getElementById('YourEMail').disabled = true

function enableDisable(bEnable, textBoxID) {
  document.getElementById(textBoxID).disabled = !bEnable
  if (document.getElementById(textBoxID).disabled)
    document.getElementById(textBoxID).value = ''
}
```

```html
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="YourEMail" id="YourEMail" style="width: 250px;">
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="enableDisable(this.checked, 'YourEMail')" name="check_sendToEmail" value="sendToEmail">
  <span style="color:cyan;">Send output to e-mail</span>
  <br>
</form>
```